# Using CSS, can you break a line based on the halfway point of the text?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, word-wrap

If I have a container with some text in it, is there a way to break the line in half, rather than based on some fixed width?

For example, I would normally assign a width (say, 200px) to a container before placing some text in it. Often this can lead to an awkward line break where only the last word in a header must wrap.

`This is a header that is
long`

versus

`This is a header
that is long`

Ideally it would *only* break if the text didn't fit on one line, and if it broke, it would do so in an even way. Would be happy with just always breaking in half as well, though, since that seems pretty complex for CSS to do alone.

Comment: probably gonna need javascript

Comment: I think JS can solve it, but it's gonna be also hard to do it in JS.. CSS is imposible.. And i don't really see useful point of it to make that function for it..

Comment: It's to avoid Orphans: https://i.imgur.com/j71BZ5d.jpg

Comment: Why not use `<pre>`?

Comment: @JTrixx16 not sure I follow. The content of the text here is dynamic, and the line break won't be handcrafted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in pure CSS. This this jQuery plugin automatically breaks your line of text nicely in 2 when the container is smaller than the text width:

https://github.com/SumoSoft/PrettyBreak